# How to handle multiple file upload using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload files using PHP but the problem is that I don't know how many files I will upload.

My question is how can I upload files if I use `file[]`?

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" /> 
<br />
<label for="file">Filename:</label><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I will add just File box and I will use JavaScript to create more file input to upload but how to handle them in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried look at the $_FILES array? Also, having your submit button called "submit" will conflict with the JavaScript method of the same name in the "form" object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See: [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), [Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
    {
        // Number of uploaded files
        $num_files = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

        /** loop through the array of files ***/
        for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
        {
            // check if there is a file in the array
            if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]))
            {
                $messages[] = 'No file uploaded';
            }
            else
            {
                // copy the file to the specified dir 
                if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$upload_dir.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]))
                {
                    /*** give praise and thanks to the php gods ***/
                    $messages[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i].' uploaded';
                }
                else
                {
                    /*** an error message ***/
                    $messages[] = 'Uploading '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i].' Failed';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Actually, the recommended practice is using the move_uploaded_file() builtin.

Comment: yes, i think move_uploaded_file() is better, Thanks A lot John that's works like magic !!

Comment: There was a suggested edit to also use `array_filter` inside `count` in order to not count empty input upload fields.

Comment: @kos How is it done using `array_filter` Right now, I  have 5 input fields in my form, and if I do `$num_files = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);` I get `5` even when a user selects only 3.

Answer (score 3):

This is a preferred method of mine.  It includes a mysql insert to keep a table on the images uploaded.  It also moves the image to the admin image folder and copies the image to the user sites image folder.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
{
    $num_files = count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    for($x =0; $x< $num_files;$x++){
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'][$x];
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$x]))
        {
            $messages[] = $image.' No file uploaded."<br>"';
        }
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$x],"images/". $image)){
            $messages[] = $image .' uploaded';
        }
        copy("images/".$image, '../images/'.$image);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES ('NULL','$id','images/$image')");
    }
}
?>
<?php /*insert this into the form*/ 
$count= count($messages); for ($i =0; $i < $count; $i++){echo $messages[$i]."<br>";}
  ?>
```

Comment: does not work count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])... always return 1..even if file/s is/are loaded 1/10 and even not loaded.. sry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image_file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['image_file'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($file['name']); $i++){
        $image = array(
            'name' => $file['name'][$i],
            'type' => $file['type'][$i],
            'size' => $file['size'][$i],
            'tmp_name' => $file['tmp_name'][$i],
            'error' => $file['error'][$i]
        );
// Here is your code to handle one file
}
```

In your code, just use '$image' instead of '$_FILES' ...

Answer (score 1):

**Ajax js**

> ```
> (function(){
>
> var d = document, w = window;
>
> /**
>  * Get element by id
>  */   
> function get(element){
>   if (typeof element == "string")
>       element = d.getElementById(element);
>   return element;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Attaches event to a dom element
>  */
> function addEvent(el, type, fn){
>   if (w.addEventListener){
>       el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
>   } else if (w.attachEvent){
>       var f = function(){
>         fn.call(el, w.event);
>       };          
>       el.attachEvent('on' + type, f)
>   }
> }
>
>
> /**
>  * Creates and returns element from html chunk
>  */
> var toElement = function(){
>   var div = d.createElement('div');
>   return function(html){
>       div.innerHTML = html;
>       var el = div.childNodes[0];
>       div.removeChild(el);
>       return el;
>   }
> }();
>
> function hasClass(ele,cls){
>   return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
> }
> function addClass(ele,cls) {
>   if (!hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
> }
> function removeClass(ele,cls) {
>   var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
>   ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
> }
>
>
> if (document.documentElement["getBoundingClientRect"]){
>
>   var getOffset = function(el){
>       var box = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
>       doc = el.ownerDocument,
>       body = doc.body,
>       docElem = doc.documentElement,
>
>       // for ie 
>       clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0,
>       clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0,
>
>       // In Internet Explorer 7 getBoundingClientRect property is treated as physical,
>       // while others are logical. Make all logical, like in IE8.
>
>
>       zoom = 1;
>       if (body.getBoundingClientRect) {
>           var bound = body.getBoundingClientRect();
>           zoom = (bound.right - bound.left)/body.clientWidth;
>       }
>       if (zoom > 1){
>           clientTop = 0;
>           clientLeft = 0;
>       }
>       var top = box.top/zoom + (window.pageYOffset || docElem && docElem.scrollTop/zoom || body.scrollTop/zoom) - clientTop,
>       left = box.left/zoom + (window.pageXOffset|| docElem && docElem.scrollLeft/zoom || body.scrollLeft/zoom) - clientLeft;
>
>       return {
>           top: top,
>           left: left
>       };
>   }
>
> } else {
>   // Get offset adding all offsets 
>   var getOffset = function(el){
>       if (w.jQuery){
>           return jQuery(el).offset();
>       }       
>
>       var top = 0, left = 0;
>       do {
>           top += el.offsetTop || 0;
>           left += el.offsetLeft || 0;
>       }
>       while (el = el.offsetParent);
>
>       return {
>           left: left,
>           top: top
>       };
>   }
> }
>
> function getBox(el){
>   var left, right, top, bottom;   
>   var offset = getOffset(el);
>   left = offset.left;
>   top = offset.top;
>
>   right = left + el.offsetWidth;
>   bottom = top + el.offsetHeight;     
>
>   return {
>       left: left,
>       right: right,
>       top: top,
>       bottom: bottom
>   };
> }
>
> /**
>  * Crossbrowser mouse coordinates
>  */
> function getMouseCoords(e){       
>
>   if (!e.pageX && e.clientX){
>       // In Internet Explorer 7 some properties (mouse coordinates) are treated as physical,
>       // while others are logical (offset).
>       var zoom = 1;   
>       var body = document.body;
>
>       if (body.getBoundingClientRect) {
>           var bound = body.getBoundingClientRect();
>           zoom = (bound.right - bound.left)/body.clientWidth;
>       }
>
>       return {
>           x: e.clientX / zoom + d.body.scrollLeft + d.documentElement.scrollLeft,
>           y: e.clientY / zoom + d.body.scrollTop + d.documentElement.scrollTop
>       };
>   }
>
>   return {
>       x: e.pageX,
>       y: e.pageY
>   };      
>
> }
> /**
>  * Function generates unique id
>  */       
> var getUID = function(){
>   var id = 0;
>   return function(){
>       return 'ValumsAjaxUpload' + id++;
>   }
> }();
>
> function fileFromPath(file){
>   return file.replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, "");           
> }
>
> function getExt(file){
>   return (/[.]/.exec(file)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(file.toLowerCase()) : '';
> }         
>
> // Please use AjaxUpload , Ajax_upload will be removed in the next version
> Ajax_upload = AjaxUpload = function(button, options){
>   if (button.jquery){
>       // jquery object was passed
>       button = button[0];
>   } else if (typeof button == "string" && /^#.*/.test(button)){                   
>       button = button.slice(1);               
>   }
>   button = get(button);   
>
>   this._input = null;
>   this._button = button;
>   this._disabled = false;
>   this._submitting = false;
>   // Variable changes to true if the button was clicked
>   // 3 seconds ago (requred to fix Safari on Mac error)
>   this._justClicked = false;
>   this._parentDialog = d.body;
>
>   if (window.jQuery && jQuery.ui && jQuery.ui.dialog){
>       var parentDialog = jQuery(this._button).parents('.ui-dialog');
>       if (parentDialog.length){
>           this._parentDialog = parentDialog[0];
>       }
>   }           
>
>   this._settings = {
>       // Location of the server-side upload script
>       action: 'upload.php',           
>       // File upload name
>       name: 'userfile',
>       // Additional data to send
>       data: {},
>       // Submit file as soon as it's selected
>       autoSubmit: true,
>       // The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
>       // Html and xml are detected automatically.
>       // Only useful when you are using json data as a response.
>       // Set to "json" in that case. 
>       responseType: false,
>       // When user selects a file, useful with autoSubmit disabled            
>       onChange: function(file, extension){},                  
>       // Callback to fire before file is uploaded
>       // You can return false to cancel upload
>       onSubmit: function(file, extension){},
>       // Fired when file upload is completed
>       // WARNING! DO NOT USE "FALSE" STRING AS A RESPONSE!
>       onComplete: function(file, response) {}
>   };
>
>   // Merge the users options with our defaults
>   for (var i in options) {
>       this._settings[i] = options[i];
>   }
>
>   this._createInput();
>   this._rerouteClicks();
> }
>
> // assigning methods to our class
> AjaxUpload.prototype = {
>   setData : function(data){
>       this._settings.data = data;
>   },
>   disable : function(){
>       this._disabled = true;
>   },
>   enable : function(){
>       this._disabled = false;
>   },
>   // removes ajaxupload
>   destroy : function(){
>       if(this._input){
>           if(this._input.parentNode){
>               this._input.parentNode.removeChild(this._input);
>           }
>           this._input = null;
>       }
>   },              
>   /**
>    * Creates invisible file input above the button 
>    */
>   _createInput : function(){
>       var self = this;
>       var input = d.createElement("input");
>       input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
>       input.setAttribute('name', this._settings.name);
>       var styles = {
>           'position' : 'absolute'
>           ,'margin': '-5px 0 0 -175px'
>           ,'padding': 0
>           ,'width': '220px'
>           ,'height': '30px'
>           ,'fontSize': '14px'                             
>           ,'opacity': 0
>           ,'cursor': 'pointer'
>           ,'display' : 'none'
>           ,'zIndex' :  2147483583 //Max zIndex supported by Opera 9.0-9.2x 
>           // Strange, I expected 2147483647                   
>       };
>       for (var i in styles){
>           input.style[i] = styles[i];
>       }
>
>       // Make sure that element opacity exists
>       // (IE uses filter instead)
>       if ( ! (input.style.opacity === "0")){
>           input.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
>       }
>
>       this._parentDialog.appendChild(input);
>
>       addEvent(input, 'change', function(){
>           // get filename from input
>           var file = fileFromPath(this.value);    
>           if(self._settings.onChange.call(self, file, getExt(file)) == false ){
>               return;             
>           }                                                       
>           // Submit form when value is changed
>           if (self._settings.autoSubmit){
>               self.submit();                      
>           }                       
>       });
>
>       // Fixing problem with Safari
>       // The problem is that if you leave input before the file select dialog opens
>       // it does not upload the file.
>       // As dialog opens slowly (it is a sheet dialog which takes some time to open)
>       // there is some time while you can leave the button.
>       // So we should not change display to none immediately
>       addEvent(input, 'click', function(){
>           self.justClicked = true;
>           setTimeout(function(){
>               // we will wait 3 seconds for dialog to open
>               self.justClicked = false;
>           }, 3000);           
>       });     
>
>       this._input = input;
>   },
>   _rerouteClicks : function (){
>       var self = this;
>
>       // IE displays 'access denied' error when using this method
>       // other browsers just ignore click()
>       // addEvent(this._button, 'click', function(e){
>       //   self._input.click();
>       // });
>
>       var box, dialogOffset = {top:0, left:0}, over = false;                          
>       addEvent(self._button, 'mouseover', function(e){
>           if (!self._input || over) return;
>           over = true;
>           box = getBox(self._button);
>
>           if (self._parentDialog != d.body){
>               dialogOffset = getOffset(self._parentDialog);
>           }   
>       });
>
>
>       // we can't use mouseout on the button,
>       // because invisible input is over it
>       addEvent(document, 'mousemove', function(e){
>           var input = self._input;            
>           if (!input || !over) return;
>
>           if (self._disabled){
>               removeClass(self._button, 'hover');
>               input.style.display = 'none';
>               return;
>           }   
>
>           var c = getMouseCoords(e);
>
>           if ((c.x >= box.left) && (c.x <= box.right) && 
>           (c.y >= box.top) && (c.y <= box.bottom)){           
>               input.style.top = c.y - dialogOffset.top + 'px';
>               input.style.left = c.x - dialogOffset.left + 'px';
>               input.style.display = 'block';
>               addClass(self._button, 'hover');                
>           } else {        
>               // mouse left the button
>               over = false;
>               if (!self.justClicked){
>                   input.style.display = 'none';
>               }
>               removeClass(self._button, 'hover');
>           }           
>       });         
>
>   },
>   /**
>    * Creates iframe with unique name
>    */
>   _createIframe : function(){
>       // unique name
>       // We cannot use getTime, because it sometimes return
>       // same value in safari :(
>       var id = getUID();
>
>
>       var iframe = toElement('<iframe src="javascript:false;" name="' + id + '" />');
>       iframe.id = id;
>       iframe.style.display = 'none';
>       d.body.appendChild(iframe);         
>       return iframe;                      
>   },
>   /**
>    * Upload file without refreshing the page
>    */
>   submit : function(){
>       var self = this, settings = this._settings; 
>
>       if (this._input.value === ''){
>           // there is no file
>           return;
>       }
>
>       // get filename from input
>       var file = fileFromPath(this._input.value);         
>
>       // execute user event
>       if (! (settings.onSubmit.call(this, file, getExt(file)) == false)) {
>           // Create new iframe for this submission
>           var iframe = this._createIframe();
>
>           // Do not submit if user function returns false                                     
>           var form = this._createForm(iframe);
>           form.appendChild(this._input);
>
>           form.submit();
>
>           d.body.removeChild(form);               
>           form = null;
>           this._input = null;
>
>           // create new input
>           this._createInput();
>
>           var toDeleteFlag = false;
>
>           addEvent(iframe, 'load', function(e){
>
>               if (// For Safari
>                   iframe.src == "javascript:'%3Chtml%3E%3C/html%3E';" ||
>                   // For FF, IE
>                   iframe.src == "javascript:'<html></html>';"){                       
>
>                   // First time around, do not delete.
>                   if( toDeleteFlag ){
>                       // Fix busy state in FF3
>                       setTimeout( function() {
>                           d.body.removeChild(iframe);
>                       }, 0);
>                   }
>                   return;
>               }               
>
>               var doc = iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument : frames[iframe.id].document;
>
>               // fixing Opera 9.26
>               if (doc.readyState && doc.readyState != 'complete'){
>                   // Opera fires load event multiple times
>                   // Even when the DOM is not ready yet
>                   // this fix should not affect other browsers
>                   return;
>               }
>
>               // fixing Opera 9.64
>               if (doc.body && doc.body.innerHTML == "false"){
>                   // In Opera 9.64 event was fired second time
>                   // when body.innerHTML changed from false 
>                   // to server response approx. after 1 sec
>                   return;             
>               }
>
>               var response;
>
>               if (doc.XMLDocument){
>                   // response is a xml document IE property
>                   response = doc.XMLDocument;
>               } else if (doc.body){
>                   // response is html document or plain text
>                   response = doc.body.innerHTML;
>                   if (settings.responseType && settings.responseType.toLowerCase() == 'json'){
>                       // If the document was sent as 'application/javascript' or
>                       // 'text/javascript', then the browser wraps the text in a <pre>
>                       // tag and performs html encoding on the contents.  In this case,
>                       // we need to pull the original text content from the text node's
>                       // nodeValue property to retrieve the unmangled content.
>                       // Note that IE6 only understands text/html
>                       if (doc.body.firstChild && doc.body.firstChild.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'PRE'){
>                           response = doc.body.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
>                       }
>                       if (response) {
>                           response = window["eval"]("(" + response + ")");
>                       } else {
>                           response = {};
>                       }
>                   }
>               } else {
>                   // response is a xml document
>                   var response = doc;
>               }
>
>               settings.onComplete.call(self, file, response);
>
>               // Reload blank page, so that reloading main page
>               // does not re-submit the post. Also, remember to
>               // delete the frame
>               toDeleteFlag = true;
>
>               // Fix IE mixed content issue
>               iframe.src = "javascript:'<html></html>';";                                     
>           });
>
>       } else {
>           // clear input to allow user to select same file
>           // Doesn't work in IE6
>           // this._input.value = '';
>           d.body.removeChild(this._input);                
>           this._input = null;
>
>           // create new input
>           this._createInput();                        
>       }
>   },      
>   /**
>    * Creates form, that will be submitted to iframe
>    */
>   _createForm : function(iframe){
>       var settings = this._settings;
>
>       // method, enctype must be specified here
>       // because changing this attr on the fly is not allowed in IE 6/7       
>       var form = toElement('<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>');
>       form.style.display = 'none';
>       form.action = settings.action;
>       form.target = iframe.name;
>       d.body.appendChild(form);
>
>       // Create hidden input element for each data key
>       for (var prop in settings.data){
>           var el = d.createElement("input");
>           el.type = 'hidden';
>           el.name = prop;
>           el.value = settings.data[prop];
>           form.appendChild(el);
>       }           
>       return form;
>   }   
> };
> })();
> ```

**jquery code for uploading**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var btnUpload=$('#browse');
            $("#hidauto").css('display','block');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: '<?=site_url('brand/upload_image1/')?>',
            name: 'file',
             onSubmit: function(file, ext){$("#loadgif1").css("display","block");

                     if (! (ext && /^(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/.test(ext))){

                        // extension is not allowed
                    //document.getElementById("loadgif").style.display='block';
                    $("#loadgif1").css("display","none");
                   $("#image").css("display","block");

                $("#image").html("only jpg,jpeg,png, images are allowed");

                        return false;

                   }
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
            //alert(response);
    if(response=='0'){
             $("#primimage1_error").html("This image is too small please upload a bigger one");
                            $("#loadgif1").css("display","none");

             return false;
    }
            $("#hidauto").css('display','block');
            $("#loadgif1").css("display","none");
             $("#image").html("");
            var r=response;
            //document.getElementById("imghid").value=response;
            divid=r.replace(new RegExp(".jpg", 'g'),'');
            divid=divid.replace(new RegExp(".jpeg", 'g'),'');
            divid=divid.replace(new RegExp(".png", 'g'),'');
            //alert(divid);     
            document.getElementById("imghidall").value=document.getElementById("imghidall").value+response+",";
            shw='<div style="float: left; height:135px; width:147px;" id='+divid+'><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/'+response+'" width="125px" height="115px"  /><div style="width: 125px;"><input type="radio" name="checkPrimary"  title="Set as Primary image" value="'+divid+'" onClick="primaryimg('+"'"+r+"'"+');" style="margin:5px"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/img_delete.png" width="17px" height="17px" title="delete" onClick="delete_image('+"'"+r+"'"+');" width="15px;" height="15px" style="float:right; margin-top:3px;"></div></div>';
            //      shw='<div style="float: left; height:135px; width:147px;" id='+divid+'><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/'+response+'" width="125px" height="115px"  /><div style="width: 125px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkPrimary" value="'+divid+'" onClick="primaryimg('+"'"+r+"'"+');" style="margin:5px"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/remove.png" title="delete" onClick="delete_image('+"'"+r+"'"+');" width="15px;" height="15px" style="float:right; margin-top:2px;"></div></div>';
                       //alert(shw);
                       $("#hidauto").append( shw ); 
                     $("#primimage1_error").html("");
                        //location.reload();
            }
        });
        });
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="r8_prt"  style="margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="line1">
        <label style="float: left; width: 121px; margin-right:10%;">Upload images&nbsp;:&nbsp;</label><input type="file" name="browse" id="browse" multiple="true"  style="float: left;">
        <label class="error" for="dwn" id="allimg_error" style="display:block; color: #B94A48;font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold; text-align:center;" ></label>
        <label class="error" for="dwn" id="primimage1_error" style="display:block; color: #B94A48;font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold; text-align:center;" ></label>
        <label id="loadgif1" style="display:none; width:10px; float:left"><img style="margin-top:-10px" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/ajax-loader(2).gif"></label>
        <div id="image" style="float:left; width:110%; margin-top:20px; color:#F00;">


      </div> 
      <div id="hidauto">

                </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="imghid" name="imghid">
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="imghidall" name="imghidall">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Upload function(For Codeigniter)**

```
    function upload_image1()    {   
    $ext=$_FILES['file']['name'];
             $epld=explode('.',$ext);   
        $nn= count($epld);$nn-=1;   
            $photo=date("MdyHis").".".$epld[$nn];       
    $data = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $width = $data[0];
            $height = $data[1]; if($width<250 || $height<250){ echo 0; die(); } 


      if(  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./uploads/".$photo)){

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';   
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';   
$config['max_size'] = '15360'; //15MB 
$config['max_width']  = '0';//'2000' 
$config['max_height']  = '0';//'2000'
$config['min_width']  = '250';//'2000'      
$config['min_height']  = '250';//'2000' 
$this->load->library('upload', $config); 
echo $photo;
   }  }
```

**Delete Image**

```
function delete_image(name)
    {
    var answer = confirm ("Do you want to delete this image?")
    if (!answer)
                {
                }
    else{


            var base_url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url+"index.php/brand/delete_image/?imgname="+name,
            data:'',
            success: function(view)
            {
            name=name+",";
            allname=document.getElementById("imghidall").value;
            e=document.getElementById("imghidall").value = allname.replace(new RegExp(name, 'g'),'');

            divid=name.replace(new RegExp(".jpg,", 'g'),'');
            divid=divid.replace(new RegExp(".jpeg,", 'g'),'');
            divid=divid.replace(new RegExp(".png,", 'g'),'');
            //alert(divid); 
            document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML="";
            $("#"+divid).css('width','0px');

            }
        });
        }
    }
```

**Delete image function**

```
function delete_image(){
    $file_name=$_GET['imgname'];
    unlink(FCPATH . '/uploads/' . $file_name);  
    unlink(FCPATH . '/uploads/thumb/' . $file_name);    
    unlink(FCPATH . '/uploads/watermark/' . $file_name);    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
                $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
//. time() . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i] becomes the name of the files
                    $file[$i] = $newFilePath = "upload/myfolder/" . time() . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                    if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                        $file[$i] = $newFilePath = "upload/myfolder/" . time() . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

PUT THIS SIMPLE SCRIPT INTO PHP SCRIPT OR FUNCTION. NB:

> $_FILES['file']

because `<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" />`