# PHP file upload count set file

Tags: php, file, upload, count

I want to count set file upload. Here is my using code. Are there any better method to do this. Thanks.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="new_image[]"  type="file" />
    <input name="new_image[]" type="file" />
    <input name="new_image[]" type="file" />
    <input name="new_image[]" type="file" />
    <input name="new_image[]" type="file" />
<button name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
<?php

$img_error = '0';
$fill_img_count = '0';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $img_count = count($_FILES['new_image']);
    echo "Total : ".$img_count."<br>";
    for ($i=0 ; $i<=$img_count ; $i++)
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['new_image']) && !empty($_FILES['new_image']['name'][$i]))
        {
            $fill_img_count++;
        }
    }
    echo "Set : ".$fill_img_count."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend testing each `['error']` key against [UPLOAD_ERR_OK](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$count_files = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['picture']['error'] as $item) {
    if ($item != 4) {
        $count_files++;
    }
}
echo $count_files;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't require to have `name="new_image[]"` as the name ... just new_image will suffice.  If you post 1 or many, on the PHP side, you'll see $_FILES[]

Some useful links for you:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Some code:

```
  if (empty($_FILES)) { echo "0 files uploaded"; } 
  else { echo count($_FILES) . " files uploaded"; }
```

**Edit** based on comment:

- [How to handle multiple file upload using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233816/how-to-handle-multiple-file-upload-using-php)

From that post:

```
  echo count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: This code will fail in case empty file fields are sent which is something OP is explicitly looking to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach($_FILES['new_image']['error'] as $status){
    if($status === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $count++;
    }
}
var_dump($count);
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="new_image[]"  type="file" />
    <input name="new_image[]" type="file" />
    <input name="new_image[]" type="file" />
    <input name="new_image[]" type="file" />
    <input name="new_image[]" type="file" />
<button name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```