# PHP count() not count correctly

Tags: php, upload

i am trying to upload multiple files to a directory.
the code i have "written" works for one file, however when i try to upload multiple files it does not work. i have tried to determine where the fault is and i believe it has something to do with count. although when i try to echo how many files are being counted i always get '1' regardless of how many files i have selected. i know this will only work for one file as the variable i am returning is always '1', and therefore will only work for one file.

to gather the files i am using html form with post method
html:

```
<form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend>HTML File Upload</legend>

<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />

<div>
    <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
</div>

<div id="submit">
    <button type="submit">Upload Files</button>
</div>

</fieldset>

</form>
```

the javascript i am using enables drag and drop feature and was sourced from:
http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/

the culprit
PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name'])) {
    // Number of uploaded files
    $num_files = count($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name']);
    echo $num_files;
    /** loop through the array of files ***/
    for($i=0; $i <= $num_files;$i++) {
        // check if there is a file in the array
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
            $messages[] = 'No file uploaded';
        }
        else {
            $unique = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);

            $newImg = "img".$unique;

            $filename  = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
            $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            //$new       = md5($filename).'.'.$extension;

            $the_file_type = $_FILES['fileselect']['type'][$i];
            $the_file_size = $_FILES['fileselect']['size'][$i] / 1024;
            $the_file_name = $_FILES['fileselect']['name'][$i];

            $ok=1;
            //This is our size condition 
            if ($uploaded_size > 350000) { 
                $messages[] =  "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
                $ok=0; 
            } 

            //This is our limit file type condition 
            if ($uploaded_type =="text/php") { 
                $messages[] =  "No PHP files<br>"; 
                $ok=0; 
            } 

            //Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
            if ($ok==0) { 
                $messages[] =  "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
            } 

            //If everything is ok we try to upload it 
            else { 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name'][$i], "uploads/{$newImg}")) { 
                    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'][$i]). " has been uploaded";
                    echo "<br />";
                    //echo $the_file_type;
                    //echo "<br />";
                    //echo $unique;
                    //echo "<span>schmeckle!</span>";
                    //echo "<br />";
                    //echo $the_file_size;
                    //echo "<br />";
                    //echo $the_file_name;

                    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO interviews_media_images SET ";
                        $insertSQL .= "fileType='$the_file_type', ";
                        $insertSQL .= "fileRef='$newImg', ";
                        $insertSQL .= "fileSize='$the_file_size', ";
                        $insertSQL .= "fileName='$the_file_name' ";

                    echo $insertSQL;

                    //mysql_query( $insertSQL);

                    //echo mysql_error();

                } else { 
                    $messages[] = "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you even `print_r($_FILES)` to see what it actually contains? I believe it's `$_FILES['fileselect'][$i]['attribute']` not `$_FILES['fileselect']['attribute'][$i]`

Comment: everything above: "for($i=0; $i <= $num_files;$i++){... blah}else{" , was referenced from another post on stack, which apparently works.
link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233816/how-to-handle-multiple-file-upload-using-php
everything below works. my problem is that "$num_files = count($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name']);" always returns '1'.

Comment: My first guess is that there is NOT a bug in the PHP `count()` function

Comment: Try doing it this way: `$_FILES['fileselect'][$i]['tmp_name']` or `count($_FILES['fileselect'])`

Comment: thanks guys. 
although taking out ['tmp_name'] from "$num_files = count($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name']);" now gives 5, and still only adds the first entry to the directory.

Comment: moving "[$i]" about has not affected a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file with the contents as follows, running PHP version 5.5.15 and it counts correctly:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['fileselect']['tmp_name']))
{
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES); echo "</pre>";
    echo "Number of files uploaded: " . count($_FILES['fileselect']['name']);
}
?>

<form id="upload" action="files_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend>HTML File Upload</legend>

<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />

<div>
    <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
</div>

<div id="submit">
    <button type="submit">Upload Files</button>
</div>

</fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: you need to better explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running in my case and $num_files returns true value after count.

One more thing to do that remove '**=**' from for loop and write like this

```
for( $i=0; $i<$num_files; $i++)
```

if you use **$i <= $num_files** it gives you a notice.

Suppose you are selecting 3 files and you are setting **$i <= $num_files**.

So for loop starts from 0 and as you selected 3 files, it continue for 4 times

0
1
2
3

You can see that the loop is continued for 4 times but it has no file on

```
$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][3].
```

I hope this will help you...

Sorry for my english.