# How do I handle multiple files at once uploaded to a PHP page via an HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have the following in an HTML form:

```
<input type="file" name="frontimage" id="frontimage" />
<input type="file" name="backimage" id="backimage" />
<input type="file" name="extraimage" id="extraimage" />
```

I need to access all three of these images and upload them via PHP. I know how to do this with ONE file, but not three. How do I access each one and upload it?

Right now I am using this code to upload just a single file:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path);
```

How do I do multiple at once? Note that I need to know which file is which, so an array of files won't work by just `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`... I need to move each individually to a certain location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to handle multiple file upload using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233816/how-to-handle-multiple-file-upload-using-php)

Comment: You already assigned three distinct form `name=` ids. Why don't you just adapt the primary `$_FILES` key `["file"]` to access each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["frontimage"]["tmp_name"], $path);  
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["backimage"]["tmp_name"], $path);   
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["extraimage"]["tmp_name"], $path);
```

You can handle each file separately

Comment: I am getting the error `Undefined index: frontimage` when trying to use this code. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using post method with enctype="multipart/form-data"