# how to upload multiple files in php?

Tags: php

i have this code in html

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file1"/><br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file2"/><br />
```

here is my php code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
            $ext=explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
            $new_name=$property_id."_".rand(10,10000).".".end($ext);
            $name=SITEPATH.S_LOCATIONS_LARGE.$new_name;
            $small=SITEPATH.S_LOCATIONS.$new_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$name);
            if(is_file($name)) {
                $this->db->update("insert into bloom_location_images (image,property_id) values ('$new_name',$property_id)");
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($name);
                if($width > 600) {
                    $this->magic->constrain_by_scale($name,500,0);
                }
                copy($name,$small);
                if($width > 301) {
                    $this->magic->constrain_by_scale($small,301,0);
                }
            }
        }

        return $property_id
```

now i want to store this two files but i cant. i think i have to pass it through array element. if yes then please tell me how is it possible

```
    please help me to do this
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple file upload using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233816/how-to-handle-multiple-file-upload-using-php)

Answer (score 3):

try this instead:

```
<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

of course add as many `<input>` as you want

**PHP**

your files will be available in the `$_FILES` array. So you can simply do something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
    $tmp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $path = "yourfolder/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path)) {
         // your code here
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: but i want to use different input control like in my question like this <input type="file" name="file" id="file1"/><br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file2"/><br />

Comment: as i said, as add many input as you want.. `<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" /><br /> <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" /> <br />` and so on...

Comment: again i want to know file extension which gonna be uploaded so how can i find it i had tried this code $ext=explode('.',$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);

Answer (score 1):

Change the `name` attribute not `id` and it will work.

Or meaby You could use something like that (HTML5 only):
[How can I select and upload multiple files with HTML and PHP, using HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post)

Comment: but i want to use different input control like in my question like this <input type="file" name="file" id="file1"/><br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file2"/><br />

Comment: again i want to know file extension which gonna be uploaded so how can i find it i had tried this code $ext=explode('.',$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);

Answer (score 0):

User array try name in form file element like this

```
<input name="image[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

And you will get upload data in `$_FILES` as array

Comment: but i want to use different input control like in my question like this <input type="file" name="file" id="file1"/><br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file2"/><br />

Comment: Meaby I didnt described it in the right way, sure thing You can edit the `id` of the field but You cant keep them both with name `file` You have to for example change it to `field[]` so they will come to backend as array or just give them different names like `field1` `field2`.
I hope that now everything is crystal clear.

Comment: again i want to know file extension which gonna be uploaded so how can i find it i had tried this code $ext=explode('.',$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);