# PHP multiple file upload script storing file path in different rows

Tags: php

The HTML script below collects user information and files and posts to the database. the challenge is that when the files are multiple, it send the file path to different rows. please assist me to configure the upload file to send the file path for images per upload to one row. thank you.

HTML

Hotel Name *

                
                    Town/City *

        
         "/>
        


    
        **(+) Add file**

Upload.php.

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
if ($_POST["action"] == "Upload")
    die ("Error: no files uploaded!");

$file_count = count($_FILES["item_file"]['name']);

echo $file_count . " file(s) sent... <BR><BR>";

if(count($_FILES["item_file"]['name'])>0) { //check if any file uploaded

    for($j=0; $j < count($_FILES["item_file"]['name']); $j++) { //loop the uploaded file array

        $filen = $_FILES["item_file"]['name'][$j];  

        // ingore empty input fields
        if ($filen!="")
        {

            // destination path - you can choose any file name here (e.g. random)
            $path = "images/" . $filen; 

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["item_file"]['tmp_name']["$j"],$path)) { 

            echo "File# ".($j+1)." ($filen) uploaded successfully!<br>"; 

            } else
            {
                echo  "Errors occoured during file upload!";
            }
            //create array of temporarily grab variables
            $input_arr=array();

            //grabs the post variables and adds slashes
            foreach($_POST as $key=> $input_arr){
                $_POST[$key]=addslashes($input_arr);
            }

            mysql_select_db("fcom_com") or die("Could not select database");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contri (field_1,field_2,URL)
                VALUES('".$_POST['field_1']."','".$_POST['field_2']."','".$_FILES['item_file']['name']["$j"]."')");
        }       
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple file upload using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233816/how-to-handle-multiple-file-upload-using-php)