# PHP move_uploaded_file for a directory uploaded

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload, scandir

I'm developing an app that should upload with a for a directory to the server, I've alredy change the configuration for the max upload size in the `php.ini`indeed the upload is done correctly.
I know the function move_uploaded_file to "store" a single file uploaded but my question is there is a way to use it for a directory uploaded?

This is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    } else {
        $storagename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $storagename);
    }
}
$a= scandir("upload");
print_r($a);
```

With this code the result of the print is this:

```
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. )
```

How can solve it?

Thank's

Comment: you want to upload directory or multiple files??

Comment: you want something like copying whole directory from one place to another place something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050859/copy-entire-contents-of-a-directory-to-another-using-php ?

Comment: and please atleast print_r $_FILES and check how does it look, give some efforts mate

Comment: If I'm not mistaken a directory upload will simply gather and upload all files in the directory so you're going to have mutliple file entries in you array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233816/how-to-handle-multiple-file-upload-using-php would work in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate the $_FILES["file"]["name"].

I think this post can help you:
[How to upload folder with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008406/how-to-upload-folder-with-php)